# void* vs vector<uint8_t> in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, void

When am dealing with the unsigned data types, i have a requirement to have a generic container that would accommodate `uint8`,`uint16`,`uint32` and `uint64` types.
Having a `void*` and casting the above data types helped me, still replacing them instead with `vector<uint8_t>` made the code look more clean.

```
void* test = (uint32_t) 100;
```

vs

pushing the same thing bytewise onto a vector test;

which would be a better and cleaner solution.

PS: i cant use boost, due to restrictions in module.

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are ACTUALLY dealing with, as I get the feeling this is very much an XY question. There are several ways that you can solve a "generic data storage", and neither `vector<uint8_t>` or `void *` are high on my list of ideas - but to suggest a good solution requires understanding what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I seriously doubt you actually need a single class that can store arrays of each of these.  Use `vector`.

Comment: So your code is required to not compile on platforms that don't have unsigned types with **exactly** 8, 16, 32, and 64 bits? That's a bit unusual. Most programs would work just fine with unsigned types that are **at least** as large, i.e., `uint_leat8_t` rather than `uint8_t` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `union` to store and access the data. This will allow all members of the union to occupy the same memory and you can access the appropriate data type without the need for casting.

```
union UintData
{
    uint8_t  v8;
    uint16_t v16;
    uint32_t v32;
    uint64_t v64;
};

std::vector<UintData> data;
UintData test;
test.v32 = 0xffffffff;
data.push_back(data);
```

When accessing the data make sure you only access the currently active member (the last member set) otherwise the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

union could be solution, but I wonder what is the size of the vector of union after pushing uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t and uint64_t...?

I'm fun of simple solution so I would try

```
std::vector<uint64_t>
```

this case you can insert all  values.